# How can I convert a char to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring

Well this proves I'm a noob at coding! I've looked everywhere and still can't get this right.  This should be pretty simple.

I have been trying this:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
  QChar q = QChar(memblock[i]);
  QString s = QString(q);
  QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(s);
  ui->tableWidget->setItem(rowCount, colCount, item);
}
```

So I'm making table items from each string.  That's because I also couldn't figure out how to make table items from just a QChar, or plain char.

But each cell ends up with:

```
Ý
```

Whereas when I add in:

```
cout << memblock[i];
```

It properly shows:

```
RIFFd2  WAVEfmt
```

Here is the code that reads in the raw data:

```
ifstream file (text, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if (file.is_open())
{
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, size);
    file.close();
}
```

Also, when I do `cout << &memblock[i]`, for i from 0 to 4 I get: 
`RIFFd2`
`IFFd2`
`FFd2`
`Fd2`

And so on.

Comment: Could you add to the post the code which initializes the `memblock` variable

Comment: `memblock = new char[size]`

Comment: Honestly, it should be as simple as `QTableWidgetItem item = new QTableWidgetItem(memblock[i]);`

Comment: it may hardly be shorter than this - `QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QChar(memblock[i]));`

Comment: @Ivan Unfortunately that results in every cell showing `Ý`

Comment: may be you should use an array of `QString` or `QChar` instead of raw chars

Comment: I added the line `qDebug() << item` , which puts out:

`0x5a4fe20 
0x5a50130 
0x5a50210 
0x5d2bb40 
0x5d2b4b0 
0x5d2ba60 
0x5d2b750 
0x5c76b80 
0x5c76e20 
0x5c76bf0 
0x5c76950 
0x5c76b10 
0x5c76cd0 
0x6f425e0 
0x6f42810 
0x6f42650 `

Looks like the memory address of each char, which would make me think I could just change it to *memblock[i] to dereference and retrieve the real value, but doing so gives the error :

`illegal indirection`

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I decided on using Qt only for GUI aspects since I have almost no experience/knowledge of c++.  One of my main goals is to learn c++.

Similar to this guy: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195568/qt-c-vs-generic-c-and-stl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to use some simplified variant of your code with Qt 4.8.3 and MSVC 2010:

```
ui.tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);
ui.tableWidget->setRowCount(5);
char *memChunck = new char[25];
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; ++i ) {
    memChunck[i] = i + 65;
}
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; ++i ) {
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number( memChunck[i], 16).toUpper() );
    ui.tableWidget->setItem(i / 5, i % 5, item);
}
```

[image: result view]

Comment: Okay that seems fairly similar to what I have.  I may have somewhat misstated my intention though.  I don't actually want Ascii representation of my data, I want the raw data as a string.  So in other words, I want 65, 66, 67, 68, and so on.   

What I really want is this: http://imgur.com/QtaspOK

Comment: @krb686, just changed the code. On updated screenshot I've used data for table from the link you provided.

Comment: I changed my code to match yours exactly, but it's not quite there for some reason.  This is what it looks like after the change: http://imgur.com/tsJ2e22

I think this may have something to do with my `memblock`
I updated my original post showing the code I am using to read in raw data.

Comment: @krb686, yeah, it seems to me that the reason is how your `memblock` is initialized. Try to read your input file as text rather than as binary.

Comment: I got it working! Your code works perfectly actually.  I forgot I pasted the reading data section in from another file that also included `delete[] memblock;` before I started trying to make items from the memblock.

doh!